# Android Kiosk Mode

Tags: android, kiosk-mode, device-owner

I want to enable Kiosk Mode for my app. I am aware that Android supports lock task mode. However, when I call the startLockTask() method, it prompts for confirmation. To bypass this, the app needs to be set as the device owner.

How can I make my app the device owner without requiring users to factory format their phones?
What steps should I take next?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make my app the device owner without requiring users to factory format their phones?

That is not possible.

> What steps should I take next?

Allow the user to confirm that your app should enable kiosk mode.

Comment: Is there any other way to implement kiosk without lock task mode?